# Angular FeatureModule should not import FeatureRoutingModule but it should be the opposite

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to know why angular by default declare module in the following manner.

## First Option

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, Feature1RoutingModule],
  declarations: [Feature1Component],
  exports: [Feature1Component],
})
export class Feature1Module {}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'create1', component: Feature1Component }
])],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Feature1RoutingModule {}
```

My concern is that if I want to reuse the Feature1Component, I will have to import the Feature1Module which will bring also the routing.

You can use the following stackblitz to see example :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5atwq9-wrmbmr

The path 'create1' will become available if I import the module somewhere else.

Question is, what is the added value to separate Feature1RoutingModule from Feature1Module with the previous example ?

## Second Option

I would understand better to do the opposite.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [Feature1Component],
  exports: [Feature1Component],
})
export class Feature1Module {}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
Feature1Module,
RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'create1', component: Feature1Component }
])],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Feature1RoutingModule {}
```

The following example can be used : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5atwq9-j4qwdv

Is there any reason that the first option should be used instead of the second option ?

Comment: You can go the second way but it's not the standard way. Angular projects often declare the routes in a separate module as routes can easily get big in complex applications. Also I expect to import a whole module by FeatureModule and not by FeatureRoutingModule, second option is like importing a Dog by importing the Dog leg.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see your point, but that is maybe where i am confused, for me the routing is not really a part of it. You may want to embedded the component in one case and in another have it available with another path. Maybe to follow angular way I should define a FeatureSharedModule, with what I want to share?
That said I still don't see a use case were I would reuse the routing.